# Boot fails waiting for /dev/disk/by-uuid

Tags: boot, 17.04

The system is stuck waiting 90 seconds for the /dev/disk/by-uuid/* devices to show up.

When dropping me to a shell, they *do* exist.

If I try the rescue grub entry, the system boots.

```
$ cat ls-dev-disk-by-uuid 
$ cat journalctl-xb
See https://gist.github.com/ole-tange/b5da8c5188b07d0098e8b6e138823b5b
```

After rebooting 5 times it suddenly boots. So it seems it might be a race condition.

It seems I can just boot once in rescue mode, then the next boot will boot just fine. OK as a workaround, but a horrible solution.

Comment: Been getting this problem too, wasn't aware it was a common thing. Hope someone finds a fix!